# For loop through a numpy array of strings

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I imported a csv file containing zip codes as a string using the following line:

```
my_data = genfromtext('path\to\file.csv', delimiter = ',', dtype=str, autostrip=True)
```

I am importing as a string in order to keep the leading zeroes some zip codes may contain. Now I need to also loop through the entire numpy array and I wanted to do so like this:

```
for i in np.nditer(my_data): 
     do something with my_data[i]
```

But unfortunately it is returning the following error:

> Arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

Any idea how I can loop through each element of this numpy array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While looping over NumPy arrays is often not a good solution, you can do it like this:

```
for i in range(len(my_data)): 
     do something with my_data[i]
```

You might be better off reading your data into a list, process the strings, and convert into NumPy array afterwards.

Comment: This actually worked! Although it looks like its pretty slow, processing about 3 zips per second. Would you happen to know a faster way by any chance?

Comment: In NumPy you want whole-array operations. It depends very much the `do something` actually does if you can do it without loops.

Comment: Thanks I will definitely look more into it

Answer (score 1):

You should do something with `i`, not with `my_data[i]`. `i` is already your element (a part if `mydata`).
Thats why `my_data[i]` is not working, becouse `i` is not an index. it is a numpy array.

If you want to use index, and the given element too, use `enumerate()`

Example:

```
lista = [20,50,70]
for idx, element in  enumerate(lista): 
    print (idx, element)
```

For more info visit this site [numpy iteration tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.nditer.html#arrays-nditer)